# Как получить значение select

Tags: javascript, ajax, функции, переменные

Как получить значение select, вот код, не могу приспособить.

```
 var ids = $("#ids").val();
 var itog = "selectexecuted" + ids;
 var executed  = $("itog option:selected").val();
```

Имеется динамическая таблица в нее решил встроить селект, у каждой записи формируется название_столбца+ид(строки), я не могу передать строку и значение на сервер из этого селекта. Возможно есть какая то альтернатива использования выпадающего списка в таблице

```
<td name="executed" id="executed'.$row['id'].'">
<select id="selectexecuted'.$row['id'].'">
   <option>да</option>
   <option>нет</option>
```

Comment: "я не могу передать строку и значение на сервер" - почему? как Вы это делаете?

Comment: не могу получить значение выбранного селекта с нужным мне id

Comment: data:'ids='+ ids +'&executed=' + executed
Вопрос не много не так поставил, как получить текст из выбранного мною например select id="executed11" где 11 это и есть айди моей строки и передать его

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var executed  = $("#" + itog + " option:selected").val();
```

или проще:

```
var executed  = $("#" + itog).val();
```

Где находится элемент с `id="ids"`, и сколько таких элементов на странице?

Comment: он один, невидимый инпут сохрнаяет последний редактируемый

Comment: Igor, спасибо, вопрос решен, синтаксис плохо пока знаю